# Do i need to mention default maven repo url?

Tags: java, maven

i have maven project.When i try to compile my project whether repo url or without repo url it compiles fine. Below is the default
maven url i am mentioned in my pom

```
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
```

My question is do we need to mention above repo url or not ?

**EDIT:-**

I believe most of the dependiencies exists at url repo1.maven.org/maven2. I need to mention different only if some of the dependency does not exist at this url. Is that correct ? –

Comment: You don't need to put repo Url in your pom but you can configure to use accordingly if you are using some other repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url is contained in the maven super pom (model version 4.0.0).

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

It references an archive of software projects. The archive is also searchable under this adress: http://search.maven.org/#browse It comes into play when the dependecy resolution mechanism tries to find the dependencies.

Full reference here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM

In general what is contained in the super pom is contained in your pom if you do not overwrite it explicitly.

Comment: I believe most of the dependiencies exists at url http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. I need to mention different if some of the dependency does not exist at this url. Right?

Comment: You should re-phrase your question if you need more details about the meaning of the url :-)

Comment: Yes. You can also search the archive to see if your dependencies are available.

Comment: Me too. Hope that helps (i think we have kind of a race-condition here ;-) )